# How to code progress bar with spaces with html css and javascript

Tags: javascript, css, html

I have this code below. But after running you will see that there is a problem when animation starts. I want it to look nice: to color first percents part, then the other and so on till 80%. But now as you see it is a mess. Please help me with this.

my code:

```js
function loadIt() {
  var elem = document.getElementById("myBar");   
  var width = 1;
  var id = setInterval(frame, 10);
  function frame() {
    if (width >= 80) {
      clearInterval(id);
    } else {
      width++; 
      elem.style.width = width + '%'; 
    }
  }
}
```

```css
#myElement {
  width: 100%;
  background: repeating-linear-gradient(to right, green, green 10%, 
transparent 10%, transparent 12%);
}

#myBar {
  width: 0%;
  height: 30px;
  background: repeating-linear-gradient(to right, grey, grey 10%, 
transparent 10%, transparent 12%);
}
```

```html
<div id="myElement">
  <div id="myBar"></div>
</div>

<br>
<button onclick="loadIt()">Click ON</button>
```

Comment: Hi Tom. Could you please describe the desired effect more detailed? Should the green blocks be permanent? Or should these blocks appear according to your progress?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mess was caused by width calculated in percents of variable width given also in percents. Leave default outer div CSS rule in px, and change only inner div with percents

```js
function loadIt() {
  var elem = document.getElementById("myBar");   
  var width = 1;
  var id = setInterval(frame, 10);
  function frame() {
    if (width >= 80) {
      clearInterval(id);
    } else {
      width++; 
      elem.style.width = width + '%'; 
    }
  }
}
```

```css
#myElement {
  width: 100%;
  background: repeating-linear-gradient(to right, grey, grey 10px, 
transparent 10px, transparent 15px);
}

#myBar {
  width: 0%;
  height: 30px;
  background: repeating-linear-gradient(to right, green, green 10px, 
transparent 10px, transparent 15px);
}
```

```html
<div id="myElement">
  <div id="myBar"></div>
</div>

<br>
<button onclick="loadIt()">Click ON</button>
```

Comment: That's great! I thought about pixels as well, but didn't know exactly how to do that! Awesome!